Correct way to unzip the staged file in the Snowflake python UDF
I'm working on implementing PyTorch model inference in the Snowflake UDF/UDTF. I'm following the official example https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-examples#unzipping-a-staged-file
This is the most relevant bit of code from the example:
 # File lock class for synchronizing write access to /tmp.
 class FileLock:
   def __enter__(self):
       self._lock = threading.Lock()
       self._lock.acquire()
       self._fd = open('/tmp/lockfile.LOCK', 'w+')
       fcntl.lockf(self._fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
       self._fd.close()
       self._lock.release()

 # Get the location of the import directory. Snowflake sets the import
 # directory location so code can retrieve the location via sys._xoptions.
 IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME = "snowflake_import_directory"
 import_dir = sys._xoptions[IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME]

 # Get the path to the ZIP file and set the location to extract to.
 zip_file_path = import_dir + "spacy_en_core_web_sm.zip"
 extracted = '/tmp/en_core_web_sm'

 # Extract the contents of the ZIP. This is done under the file lock
 # to ensure that only one worker process unzips the contents.
 with FileLock():
    if not os.path.isdir(extracted + '/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1'):
       with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as myzip:
          myzip.extractall(extracted)

The model archive is delivered to the workspace of the UDF and is placed in the directory, that is retrieved from the sys._xoptions. The example code addresses the issue that the computation is distributed to a bunch of worker threads running on the same machine and the unzipping should be done once by one of the them, while the others should wait.
Mostly the code makes sense, except for one bit. What is the point of creating a threading.Lock instance in the __enter__ method of FileLock class and acquiring it? If this is intended to synchronize the threads, wouldn't it make sense to somehow share the lock object between the threads? Otherwise each thread creates its own instance of the lock and acquires it, how would that achieve anything?
I believe the code actually achieves its purpose by using the file lock, that is actually shared by all threads/processes running this code, because it is an exclusive file lock on the one and the same file for all of them. Am I missing something and using file lock is not enough here and the threading.Lock is also needed?

Thanks for calling attention to this issue. The team is reviewing the docs, as the lock should probably be moved into the module level.
Will update with the right code as it makes it into the official docs.
